# implementation of Lomb-Scargle periodogram

Tags: matlab, signal-processing, spectral-clustering

from matlab official site  , Lomb-Scargle periodogram is defined as

http://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/plomb.html#lomb

suppose we have some random signal let say

```
 x=rand(1,1000);
```

average of this signal can be easily implemented as

average=mean(x);
variance  can be implemented as

```
>> average_vector=repmat(average,1,1000);
>> diff=x-average_vector;
>> variance= sum(diff.*diff)/(length(x)-1);
```

how should i continue? i mean how to choose frequencies ? calculation of time offset is not problem,let us suppose that we have time vector

```
t=0:0.1:99.9;
```

so that total length of time vector be 1000,  in generally for DFT, frequencies bins are represented as a multiplier of 2*pi/N, where N is length of signal, but what about this case? thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As can be seen from [the provided link to MATLAB documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/plomb.html#lomb), the algorithm does not depend on a specific sampling times t<sub>k</sub> selection. Note that for equally spaced sampling times (as you have selected), the same link indicates:

> The offset depends only on the measurement times and vanishes when the times are equally spaced.

So, as you put it "calculation of time offset is not a problem".

Similar to the DFT which can be obtained from the [Discrete-Time Fourier Transform (DTFT)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete-time_Fourier_transform) by selecting a discrete set of frequencies, we can also *choose* `f[n] = n * sampling_rate/N` (where `sampling_rate = 10` for your selection of t<sub>k</sub>). If we disregard the value of P<sub>LS</sub>(f[n]) for `n=mN` where `m` is any integer (since it's value is ill-formed, at least in the formula posted in the link), then:

[image: \sum_{k=1}^N \cos^2(2\pi f_n t_k) = \sum_{k=1}^N \sin^2(2\pi f_n t_k) = N/]

Thus for real-valued data samples:

[image: P_{LS}(f_n) = \frac{1}{N\sigma^2} |Y(n)|^2]

where `Y` can be expressed in terms of the `diff` vector you defined as:

```
Y = fft(diff);
```

That said, as indicated on [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least-squares_spectral_analysis), the Lomb–Scargle method is primarilly intended for use with unequally spaced data.

Comment: so it means that i should take FFT of real signal ,take square of absolute value right ? then divide by N*sigma^2 ?

Comment: sorry not signal itself, but signal - average ?

Comment: so anyway,  to calculate Lomb-Scargle periodogram, i need to substract mean value from given signal ,then take fft, square of absolute value and divide by N*sigma^2 right ?

Comment: For your case of equally spaced signal, yes.

Comment: if it is not equally spaced ?

Comment: Then you'd have to go back to [the formula](http://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/plomb.html#lomb) to evaluate each summation term. The Nonuniform FFT (NFFT) and NFCT/NFST may come in handy to efficiently evaluate those terms (see eg. https://www-user.tu-chemnitz.de/~potts/nfft/).